# how to get dynamic element for ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I know i made lots of mistake thats why I come to here.
Actually I have some data

According to data I have Indication 1, Indication 2, Indication 3 and Indication 4, for each indication there is some message for user and if I select 2, 3 or 4 then the message will move to that corrosponding indication. And really I dont have idea how to do it becouse these message are coming from dynamicaly as:

```
 $i=1;
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($qry))
      {
     ?>

      <div class="solo"><div style=" width:100px;height:24px;float:left;padding:4px ;">


        <select style="width:60px;font-size:14px;" onchange="move(this.value);">

          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <!--<option value="60min">60min</option>
          <option value="other">other</option>-->
        </select>
      </div>

      <div style=" width:600px;height:24px;float:left;padding-top:8px;text-align:center;"> <?php echo $row['message'];?></div>
      <div  style=" width:100px;height:24px;float:left;padding:4px ;">
        <div style="width:100px; float:left;">
          <input style="float:left;" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" name="foo[]"/><div style="padding:2px; float:left;"><a href="delete.php?q=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" onclick="return del();">Kill</a></div>

        </div>
```

**and I am using to get these message id**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function move(str)
{

var a=document.getElementsByClassName("mid")[0].value;
alert(a);
}
</script>
```

and i display this message id as in hidden text box:

```
<input type="hidden" name="msg" class="mid" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
```

am just confuse how to get a particuler message id for each message becouse above `move()` function is only giving one id by `[0]`

So I just want to know how to do this for each element when all the input box have same class.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName("mid")` gives you an array of dom elements. You are currently taking only the first element in that array. So loop through it and get each ones `value` attribute

```
function move(str) {

  var a=document.getElementsByClassName("mid");
  for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
     alert(a[i].value);

}
```

#### update

Its not clear what you are trying to achieve.
If you are trying to alert the value of dom element with index as `str`, then the function could be as simple as

```
function move(str) {

  alert(document.getElementsByClassName("mid")[str].value);

}
```

if not please mention what you are trying to achieve in your question.

Comment: it working fine....but you know i just want to alert all different only once but this is giving all dom element value for one onchange...

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you want to iterate over the result list of getElementByClassName.

For this have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15843940/1885950

In your case it will look like:

```
var mid_holders = document.getElementsByClassName("mid");
for(var i = 0; i < mid_holders.length; i++)
{
    alert(mid_holders.item(i).value);
}
```