# Javascript: How to setValue to HTMLDivElement?

Tags: javascript

My HTML page code looks like this-

```
<div id="test-inputEl" role="textbox" class="test-field" data-errorqtip="">10</div>
```

To access this value `10` I am using below code-

```
var divObject = parent.document.getElementById('test-inputEl');
alert(divObject);
var testField = divObject.getElementsByClassName("test-field");
alert(testField);
```

For the first `alert` box I'm getting-

```
[object HTMLDivElement]
```

and for the second one I'm getting-

```
[object HTMLCollection]
```

But I can't access the value.
I have tried like this-

```
var objValue = divObject.getElementsByClassName("x-form-display-field")[0].innerHTML;
```

But not Working.
Is there any way to get this value or set this value using `javascript`. Because I'm not much familiar with `jquery`.

Comment: ...and what is parent? And why you use document.getEl.... if you use parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `innerHTML` property to get the value `10` from div.

```js
var divObject = document.getElementById('test-inputEl').innerHTML;
document.write(divObject);
```

```html
<div id="test-inputEl" role="textbox" class="test-field" data-errorqtip="">10</div>
```

Comment: Do you think ` parent.document.getElementById...` would work?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `getElementById` you retrieve the `HtmlElement` you want, but when you use `getElementsByClassName` your result is a collection of HTML element, it's NOT an array!!

to get the first item, use `myCollection.item(0)`

```
var objValue = divObject.getElementsByClassName("x-form-display-field").item(0).innerHTML;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection

[How to correctly iterate through getElementsByClassName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843581/how-to-corectly-iterate-through-getelementsbyclassname)