# Using foreach to loop through a class element

Tags: javascript

I m storing all the elements from a getElementsByClassName to a variable, I would imagine I can foreach loop this variable to get every single ids from it. But its not working.

```js
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("machine_btn_over_layer");
el.forEach(test);
var test = function() {
  console.log("test");
}
```

```html
<div class="machine_btn_over_layer"></div>
<div class="machine_btn_over_layer"></div>
<div class="machine_btn_over_layer"></div>
<div class="machine_btn_over_layer"></div>
```

What am I doing wrong? Im getting error saying function is not working

Comment: In the console you should have seen exactly what you were doing wrong: `"Uncaught TypeError: el.forEach is not a function"` You're using a function that doesn't exist; instead convert the live NodeList to an Array and then use `Array.prototype.forEach()`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843581/how-to-correctly-iterate-through-getelementsbyclassname  I think this post is more relevant in this case.

Answer (score 8):

You need to make two changes. First `document.getElementsByClassName` is a HTMLCollection so array method will not work  on this. So to use the array method you can convert it to array using `spread operator(...)`

Secondly a function declared `var test = function() {}` is never hoisted. So when `el.forEach` is called it don't get the function, hence it will throw `undefined` is not a function

```js
var el = [...document.getElementsByClassName("machine_btn_over_layer")];
var test = function() {
  console.log("test");
}
el.forEach(test);
```

```html
<div class="machine_btn_over_layer"></div>
<div class="machine_btn_over_layer"></div>
<div class="machine_btn_over_layer"></div>
<div class="machine_btn_over_layer"></div>
```

Comment: Upvote for using (...). I've never seen that syntax before!

Comment: Doesn't work in all browsers, be careful. I'd be more inclinced to use something like Array.from() to make it into an array -- even though that also doesn't work in all browsers, at least it has polyfills.

Answer (score 3):

Use the documentation to help you! [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName):

> ```
> var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(names)
> ```
>
> *elements* is a live [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of found elements.

The first thing you should notice on the `HTMLCollection` documentation is that it does *not* have a method named `forEach`. But it does have a property named `length`

> `HTMLCollection.length`
>
> Returns the number of items in the collection.

And a method named `item`

> [`HTMLCollection.item()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection/item)
>
> Returns the specific node at the given zero-based index into the list. Returns null if the index is out of range.

So you should be able to do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) test(el.item(i));
```

Or use the array sugar:

```
for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) test(el[i]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Not every browser implements `Array.prototype` methods on [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) returned by `getElementsByClassName` method.

Also variable assignments do not hoist. Function declarations do.

```js
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("machine_btn_over_layer");

// manually call Array.prototype.forEach on HTMLCollection
Array.prototype.forEach.call(el, test);

// replace function expression with function declaration to hoist with value
function test() {
  console.log("test");
}
```

```html
<div class="machine_btn_over_layer"></div>
<div class="machine_btn_over_layer"></div>
<div class="machine_btn_over_layer"></div>
<div class="machine_btn_over_layer"></div>
```