# HTMLCollection get every element from object

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make a loop for this collection to get every element? I have tried these methods but they didn't work

```
const collection = document.getElementsByClassName('fc-daygrid-day-top') the type is an object
```

**The First Method**

```
for(let arr of Array(collection)){console.log(Array(collection)[i])} // Doesn't work
```

**The second method**

```
var arr = [...collection]; // can't convert to array
```

May you know how to get every element from this object?

[image: HTML]

Comment: I tried it with `querySelectorAll()` and `forEach` and it worked.

Comment: You shouldn't convert the collection to an array in your first method example.

Comment: @ParsaArvaneh ok let me try it

Comment: If you want to stick with `getElementByClassName` see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48888574/using-foreach-to-loop-through-a-class-element

Answer (score 1):

Here `for(let arr of Array(collection))` array is created with only single element and that is `HTMLCollection` and cant iterate through. Array constructor need elements or size. Fetched `HTMLCollection` is put into array as single element.
Better use spread operator to spread elements into array.
`for(let arr of Array(...elements))`

You can either use `for let of ...` to iterate through HTMLCollection.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
    for(let element of elements)
        console.log(element.textContent);               
})
```

```html
<div class="test">1</div>
<div class="test">2</div>
<div class="test">3</div>
<div class="test">4</div>
<div class="test">5</div>
<div class="test">6</div>
```

Or convert it to array with `Array.from` and iterate

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
  Array.from(elements).map(element => console.log(element.textContent))                 
})
```