# How to select all elements with a class in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to modify all classes with JS.
Is there way to select them without manually setting the array index (for example [0] or [1] or [184])?

Example code:

```html
<div class='message'>something:</div>
<div class='message'>something</div>
```

```js
const element = document.querySelectorAll(".message");
element.classList.add("color");
```

It works only when I add `[0]` and only for the first element that has the class.
But I'd like to modify all the elements with the class.

Comment: Instead of using [0] you need to loop all the elements and use [0] to change the inner html of each element

Comment: see this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843581/how-to-correctly-iterate-through-getelementsbyclassname

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's important to learn what basic language syntax does first. The `[0]` is selecting the `0` index of an array (or array-like object). So to operate on them all, you can use a loop with a variable that is incremented starting at `0` and continuing until it goes out of bounds of the array.

```
function replaceEmotes() {
    var messages = document.querySelectorAll(".message");
    for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        var str = messages[i].innerHTML.replace(":smile:", "<i class='em em-smile'></i>");
        messages[i].innerHTML = str;
    }
}
```

There are other ways too, but this is a fundamental syntax that should probably be learned first.

Comment: @Oliver: I added code, but again, you should really be learning this basic, fundamental stuff on your own.

Comment: thanks!! :) and sorry, I am new in javaScript, I am PHP dev and only learning JS. Thx

Answer (score 7):

Use forEach to iterate over all message nodes and replace emotes. Also note that I'm using a global regexp to replace all `:smile:` strings within a message, not just the first one.

```
function replaceEmotes() {
    var messages = document.querySelectorAll(".message");

    messages.forEach(message => {
       message.innerHTML = message.innerHTML.replace(/:smile:/g, "<i class='em em-smile'></i>");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`document.querySelectorAll()` selects all elements of given class name and store them in an array-like object. It is possible to loop through the objects instead of accessing them manually.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.className');
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    var str = elements[i].innerHTML;
    elements[i].innerHTML = str.replace(":smile:", "<i class='em em-smile'></i>");
}
```

You can also do the same thing using `document.getElementsByClassName()`

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('className');
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    // Same like above...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `document.getElementsByClassName("message")` and loop through all the elements in the NodeList