# Optimize JS function getclassname

Tags: javascript, optimization

I'm really poor in JS development, and I try to optimize some code. I am following an online formationt. So sorry to maybe ask a stupid question.

I have this code to optimize:

```js
function border(){

var elmnt = document.getElementsByClassName("menu__item--link")[0];

var elmnt1 = document.getElementsByClassName("menu__item--link")[1];

var elmnt2 = document.getElementsByClassName("menu__item--link")[2];


document.getElementsByClassName("menu__item--border")[0].style.height = 'calc(' + elmnt.offsetHeight + "px" +' + 6px)';
document.getElementsByClassName("menu__item--border")[0].style.marginTop = 'calc( -'+ elmnt.offsetHeight + "px" +' - 15px)';

document.getElementsByClassName("menu__item--border")[1].style.height = 'calc(' + elmnt1.offsetHeight + "px" +' + 6px)';
document.getElementsByClassName("menu__item--border")[1].style.marginTop = 'calc( -'+ elmnt1.offsetHeight + "px" +' - 15px)';

document.getElementsByClassName("menu__item--border")[2].style.height = 'calc(' + elmnt2.offsetHeight + "px" +' + 6px)';
document.getElementsByClassName("menu__item--border")[2].style.marginTop = 'calc( -'+ elmnt2.offsetHeight + "px" +' - 15px)';

}
```

Is there a way not have to repeat for each elements of my class?
This code works for me but I try to do the best code possible.

Comment: Please check out: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843581/how-to-correctly-iterate-through-getelementsbyclassname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can destructure the whole collection into the first, second, and third items:

```
const [el1, el2, el3] = document.getElementsByClassName("menu__item--link");
```

But it'd be more DRY to use a loop instead. Save one of the collections in a variable, then iterate over the other collection, and check the index to get the linked element:

```
const links = document.getElementsByClassName("menu__item--link")
document.querySelectorAll(".menu__item--border").forEach((border, i) => {
  border.style.height = 'calc(' + links[i].offsetHeight + "px" +' + 6px)'
  border.style.marginTop = 'calc( -'+ links[i].offsetHeight + "px" +' - 15px)';
});
```

If you have more than 3 elements and only need to operate on the first 3, then slice the collection first:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll(".menu__item--border")]
  .slice(0, 3)
  .forEach((border, i) => {
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's work really fine. And the best point is that I  understood the logique !