# How can I get this changeColor function working? JavaScript with no frameworks

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I´m trying to change the color of the background (body) and some elements' text color. I want to do this by adding an "onclick" in a link from the header (the link with the class "list-3").

For the elements, I added the class "textClass" in the HTML elements I want the change to happen, and in the function I did "var textClass = document.getElementsByClassName("textClass");".

When I click on the link, nothing happens. Can anyone help me pls?
I´m new to JS, so I want to keep this as simple as possible.

```js
function changeColor(bgColor, textColor) {

    var textClass = document.getElementsByClassName("textClass");

    document.body.style.background = bgColor;
    document.textClass.style.color = textColor;
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Stuff</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton%7CMontserrat%7COpen+Sans%3A300%2C300i%2C400%2C400i%2C600%2C600i%2C700%2C700i%2C800%2C800i%7CPT+Sans%3A400%2C700&amp;ver=4.0.31" type="text/css" media="all">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">

    <script src="JS/main.js"></script>

</head>


<body>

    <header id="mainHeader">

        <div class="page-logo-nav">

            <div class="header-logo">

                <a href="index.html">
                
                    <img src= "img/logo.jpg">

                </a>
            
            </div>


            <div class="header-nav">

                <nav>

                    <ul>
                        <li class="list-1"><a href="index.html">SOBRE</a></li>
                        <li class="list-2"><a href="contactos.html">CONTACTOS</a></li>
                        <li class="list-3"><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="changeColor(yellow, red)">TEMA ESCURO</a></li>
                    </ul> 
            
                </nav>

            </div>

        </div>

    </header>


    <main>
        
        <div id="top" class="bio-image" style="background-image: url('img/allen-01.jpeg'); width: 100%; height: 99vh;">

            <div class="bio-headings">
                
                <h1>ALLEN HALLOWEEN</h1>

                <h2>BIOGRAFIA</h2>

            </div>

        
           <a href="#info" class="go-content textClass">

            <span class="arrow">&#10095;</span>

           </a> 
                
            
        </div>


        <br>
        <br>
        <br>


        <div id="info" class="info-main">
                

                <div class="info-left">

                    <h2>TUDO NO HALLOWEEN É ÚNICO...</h2>

                    <br>

                    <p class="textClass">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin et justo a enim auctor bibendum vitae sed lectus. Phasellus sit amet odio quis felis.</p>
                    

                </div>



                <div class="info-right">

                    <p class="textClass">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ultrices, velit id volutpat varius, lectus neque sagittis est, sit amet sodales dui odio at neque. Nunc aliquam volutpat quam, eu tincidunt quam bibendum sagittis. Nam accumsan nisi eu viverra commodo. Pellentesque ut ornare.</p>

                    <br>

                    <p class="textClass">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dictum volutpat molestie. Cras ac semper metus. Quisque eget quam eget orci vulputate condimentum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse eu.</p>

                </div>
```

Comment: The error in the console should tell you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: @epascarello And how can I do that?

Comment: You can press `ctrl+shift+i` to get the developer tools. open the console and you'll see the javascript logs.

Comment: You've used `getElementsByClassName` (Element[S]) it means it will return a collection of elements. Loop through it like an array with a for or foreach and set the style of one element.

Comment: @Clvckl3s In the text editor? Did that didn´t work. Sorry, I´m still a noob..

Comment: In the browser.

Answer (score 1):

This bit

```js
var textClass = document.getElementsByClassName("textClass");
```

gives you "an array-like object of all child elements" ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)).

So essentially there's two mistakes here:

- `textClass` is not the class, but all elements with that class within `document`, in an array-like structure. A better name would be something along the lines of `textClassElements`.
- You've defined that variable in your scope – it's not a property of `document`.

I'd recommend working with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) since it's easier to handle and [attach a JS event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of modifying the `onclick` property (which is discouraged).

```js
function changeColor(bgColor, textColor) {

    document.body.style.background = bgColor;
   
    var textClassElements = document.querySelectorAll('.textClass');
    textClassElements.forEach(function(element) {
       element.style.color = textColor;
    });
}

var trigger = document.querySelector('.list-3') // will only select the first element matching the selector
trigger.addEventListener('click', function() {
  changeColor('#ff0', '#f00');
});
```

within your function should do the trick.

---

Additional reading:

- [The browser console on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console)
- [Tutorials for different browsers about the browser console](https://www.wickedlysmart.com/hfjsconsole/)
- [A CodePen with your example code and my changes](https://codepen.io/DukeDiamond/pen/BaLwLej)

Comment: Thank you. But it still isn´t working. Maybe a problem in the html? Now I have my JS like this: `function changeColor(bgColor, textColor) {

 var textClassElements = document.getElementsByClassName("textClass");

 document.body.style.background = bgColor;
 
 textClassElements.forEach( function(element) {
  
    element.style.color = textColor;
  });
}; `

Comment: @epascarello yeah, I noticed now, I needed to add ' ' in "changeColor('yellow', 'red')". But it´s not working completly. It´s only changing the background color, the text color is not changing. Any suggestion?

Comment: I´m getting an error in the console log saying: Uncaught TypeError: textClassElements.forEach is not a function
    at changeColor (main.js:26)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM838 index.html:43). Can´t figure it out, I´m still new to this...

Comment: I've updated my answer – the `HTMLCollection` returned by`getElementsByClassName` is not _that_ much like an array – it does not contain the `forEach` method.

Comment: Figured it out. Did like this: for (var i = 0; i < textClassElements.length; i++) {
      
     textClassElements.item(i).style.color = textColor;
 }.  Saw in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843581/how-to-correctly-iterate-through-getelementsbyclassname/39146365

Comment: @Mr.Mediocre Thanks for the help! I solved it with this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843581/how-to-correctly-iterate-through-getelementsbyclassname/39146365. It´s because getElementsByClassName doens´t retrieve an array but a NodeList. Dont´t know the difference but yeah...