# JavaScript just not returning right length

Tags: javascript, html

So I have some JavaScript included in my HTML document, which just creates an array and writes the length of it in the Console:

```js
var Bulbs = document.getElementsByClassName("Bulb");
console.log(Bulbs.length);
```

The output I get is `0`, but when I type `Bulbs.length` directly in the Console, I get `2` as an output. Why is this so?
My HTML code:

```html
<header>
    <div class="Bulb nav">
        <a class="active">Hallo</a>
        <a>Hallo</a>
        <a>Hallo</a>
        <a>Hallo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="Bulb additional">
        <a>Impressum</a>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/un8o7cqr/ your code is working. returning 2 in the console.

Comment: You've to run the script after the page loaded.

Comment: `.getElementsByClassName` returns a live [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). At the time you're logging the length in the console, there's no elements in the collection. Later, when you check the length of the collection, the body has been parsed, and the elements exist.

Comment: @Teemu What do you mean by live? When I delete a matched element, the collection does not observe the deletion and continues with the same elements.

Comment: @Klaider Just read the linked MDN article ... The collection is live, and definitely a removed element is dropped from the live collection. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/66480319/1169519

Comment: @Teemu I see, I was using `Node.prototype.querySelectorAll()`, which returns a `NodeList`, not a `HTMLCollection`.

Comment: Yep, that returns a static list.

Comment: @Teemu , ok, and how can i fix this? Just adding a few seconds of wait to the start of my skript?

Comment: Nope, either add `defer` attribute to the script tag, or move the tag to the end of the `body`, or put your code in a `DOMContentReady` event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so putting the script at the end of the body worked. Thanks @Teemu!