# Cannot read property 'style' of undefined but styles are working

Tags: javascript, html, css

Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined. Styles are working when I'm choosing an input.
this input:

```
var input = document.getElementById('pa_rama').value;
    var option = document.getElementById('pa_razmer').value;
    let ramka = document.getElementsByClassName('woocommerce-product-gallery__image');

       if(input == 'chernaya') {
    for(var i=0; i < input.length; i++) {
      ramka[i].style.border = '50px solid black';    
      ramka[i].style.boxShadow = 'none';
}   
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: what is `ramka`?

Comment: do you mean `i < ramka.length` instead of  `i < input.length`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at this post :
[How to correctly iterate through getElementsByClassName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843581/how-to-correctly-iterate-through-getelementsbyclassname)

What you probably need to do is :

```
var input = document.getElementById('pa_rama').value;
    var option = document.getElementById('pa_razmer').value;
    let ramka = document.getElementsByClassName('woocommerce-product-gallery__image');

       if(input == 'chernaya') {
    for(var i=0; i < ramka.length; i++) { //I think you want to loop on ramka.lenght and not input.lenght, right ?
      ramka.item(i).style.border = '50px solid black';    
      ramka.item(i).style.boxShadow = 'none';
}   
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I forgot that it should be `ramka.length`

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you added the `<script> js file` in bottom of the html

or try with `onload` function in javascript

```
window.onload = function() {
   var input = document.getElementById('pa_rama').value;
   var option = document.getElementById('pa_razmer').value;
   let ramka = document.getElementsByClassName('woocommerce-product-gallery__image');

   if(input == 'chernaya') {
     for(var i=0; i < input.length; i++) {
       ramka[i].style.border = '50px solid black';    
        ramka[i].style.boxShadow = 'none';
      }   
   } 
}
```