# filtirnig script is too slow

Tags: javascript, html

I have the script below to filter unordered list of links (ul, li, a) , the problem is the search is too slow on computer and freeze completlly on mobile, the list is about 19000 link, is it a problem inn the script or is it something else, any ideas?

```
function myFunction3() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";

        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: you should use `a.textContent.trim().toUpperCase().includes(filter)`. Though it won't affect the performance AFAIK.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` is [a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66480319/1169519) in the loop, and setting inline styles is another. Use array instead of HTMLCollection, and change the class instead of setting the inline style of the elements. Reading `innerHTML` of the live document is also slow, retrieve `textContent` instead.

Comment: @teemu can you demonstrate?

Comment: Why are you rendering 19000 list items, that doesn't makes sense. i think that's too much to begin with. initally render limited number of list items, and render remaining list on demand of user.

Comment: Like [so](https://jsfiddle.net/knst6cwf/) ... If it's still slow, you can try [RegExp.test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/EXSLT/regexp/test) method instead of checking the index.

Comment: @hussain.codes it is the products list

Comment: @MrT [There's another fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/knst6cwf/1/), it uses a RegExp for filtering. The basic problems are that you're changing the layout, and then read `innerHTML`, which forces a recalculation of the layout, and secondly as it was already said in the linked answer of mine, iterating a live HTMLCollection is really slow.

Comment: I have tried your script but it didn't run

Comment: @MrT There was a typo in both of the snippets, the new definition of `for` loops is `for (i = 0, eI = li.length; i < eI; i++)`. I tested the cases. The RegExp code is slightly faster than indexOf code, these are 2 - 3 times faster than Alex' code. We're talking about 50 msecs against 150 msecs, that's negligible. Re-calculation and rendering takes the most of the used time with all of the functions. You might get this faster by using multiple `ul`s, update the lists visible on the screen first, then lazy-update the rest of the lists, An infinite scroll library might also help.

Comment: It appeared, that FF is extremely slow when creating a list of 19000 items, and also when updating it. Chromium browsers are somewhat ten times faster to create the big list and recalculate and rerender the updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I supose all the li elements are inside your ul element, so you could try something like this:

```
function myFunction3() {
 var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
 input = document.getElementById("myInput");
 filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
 ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
 ul.style.display='none'
 li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
 for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";

    }
 }
 ul.style.display='block'
}
```

This way the interface will not update visually until the for loop ends, since the parent  element will not be visible until the execution ends. I put display = 'block' only as an example.  I hope it works.

Comment: any more suggestions to enhance it?

Comment: I'm glad it works better for you. About the code, I think it's pretty cool, you could make the code one line smaller and avoid the else if you want by doing this:

    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          li[i].style.display = "";
          continue;
        }
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    }

Comment: "_the interface will not update visually until the for loop ends_" This is not quite right, the view is not repainted until all the scripts has been finished anyway. The difference here is, that setting `display: none` pulls the elements out of the textflow, that prevents the layout re-calculation when `a.innerHTML` is retrieved in the loop.