# Button Toggle On/Off Selecting Elements by the same Div Class Name

Tags: javascript, html, css, getelementsbyclassname

I am trying to simplify this code - is there a way to state/condense the script variable x 0-21 in one line of code instead of each separate line?

```
<a onclick="myFunction()" id="load_more" class="testimonials_button">View More Testimonials</a

<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("single_bottom_testi");
  x[0].style = "display:block";
x[1].style = "display:block";
x[2].style = "display:block";
x[3].style = "display:block";
x[4].style = "display:block";
x[5].style = "display:block";
x[6].style = "display:block";
x[7].style = "display:block";
x[8].style = "display:block";
x[9].style = "display:block";
x[10].style = "display:block";
x[11].style = "display:block";
x[12].style = "display:block";
x[13].style = "display:block";
x[14].style = "display:block";
x[15].style = "display:block";
x[16].style = "display:block";
x[17].style = "display:block";
x[18].style = "display:block";
x[19].style = "display:block";
x[20].style = "display:block";
x[21].style = "display:block";
}
</script>
```

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind without knowing exactly why you'd want to do this is to use a for loop to set the style `display: block` on each element, however my suggestion would be to use a class and set the property there. Check the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to correctly iterate through getElementsByClassName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843581/how-to-correctly-iterate-through-getelementsbyclassname)

Comment: also I highly recommend not to use `getElementByClassName` but to use `querySelector` or in your case `querySelectorAll` and `forEach`

Comment: I would toggle a class on one element that is an ancestor of all of those elements and use CSS to show those elements, like `.show_single_bottom_test1 .single_bottom_test1 { display: block; }` and your JavaScript does something like `document.getElementById("ancestor").classList.toggle("show_single_bottom_test1")`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a class and then adding that class to each of the elements instead of modifying the style directly.

```
<style>
.displayBlock{
  display: block;
}
</style>
<script>
function myFunction(){
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("single_bottom_testi");
  for(let i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    x[i].classList.add("displayBlock"):
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Definitely the more efficient way to do it. As the op wants all children styled, an even more efficient way would be to add the styling in css `.displayChildrenBlock > * { display: block }` then just add this class to the parent, no loop required.

Answer (score 1):

you need to do loop with new es6 code

```
document.querySelectorAll(".single_bottom_testi").forEach(item=>item.style.display="block")
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Use a "for" loop:

```js
myFunction();

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("single_bottom_testi");
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style = "display:block";
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="single_bottom_testi">Hello</button>
<button class="single_bottom_testi">World</button>
<button class="single_bottom_testi">!!!!!</button>
```

**2)** Use "forEach" loop

```js
myFunction();

function myFunction() {
  var x = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("single_bottom_testi"));
  x.forEach(e => e.style = "display:block");
}
```

```html
<button class="single_bottom_testi">Hello</button>
<button class="single_bottom_testi">World</button>
<button class="single_bottom_testi">!!!!!</button>
```

Comment: Your first snippet doesn't throw errors only because nothing is calling `myFunction`, but if something did, it would error out with `HTMLCollection` does not have a property `forEach`.

Comment: Thanks for the observation, you are right

Comment: In order to make it work using forEach, first have to convert the HTMLCollection with Array.from()

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat simple. Just make a function to set the style of the element that is passed into it's first argument, and use the `forEach` function of Array created from the node list.

```
function myFunction() {
  function setStyle(element) {
    element.style = "display: block";
  }
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("single_bottom_testi");
  x.forEach(setStyle);
}
```

Though I would not suggest setting the style property like that. Instead I would use

```js
element.style.display = "none";
```

```html
<style>
button {
  display: none;
}
</style>

<a onclick="myFunction()" id="load_more" class="testimonials_button">View More Testimonials</a>

<button class="single_bottom_testi">Button</button>
<button class="single_bottom_testi">Button</button>
<button class="single_bottom_testi">Button</button>
<button class="single_bottom_testi">Button</button>
<button class="single_bottom_testi">Button</button>
<button class="single_bottom_testi">Button</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  function setStyle(element) {
    element.style.display = "block";
  }
  var x = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("single_bottom_testi"));
  x.forEach(setStyle);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work in case you want to stick to `document.getElementsByClassName`:

```html
<a onclick="myFunction()" id="load_more" class="testimonials_button">View More Testimonials</a>
<button class="single_bottom_testi" style="display: none">Button 1</button>
<button class="single_bottom_testi" style="display: none">Button 2</button>
<button class="single_bottom_testi" style="display: none">Button 3</button>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("single_bottom_testi")).forEach(el => el.style.display = "block");
  }
</script>
```