# getElementsByTagName from a collection

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementsbyclassname, getelementsbytagname, selectors-api

EDIT: the `document.querySelectorAll` solution works, and is easier to read and understand. My own solution (in the answers, below) also works, and is slightly faster. The `getElementsByClassName + getElementsByClassName` solution is the fastest, so I've marked it as the accepted solution.

ORIGINAL POST: I need to find child  elements of any element with a particular class, e.g.,

```
<li class="myclass"><a>This is the link I need to find</a></li>
```

so that I can set and remove some attributes from the anchor.

I can easily find all of the list items with getElementsByClassName, but getElementsByTagName fails because it only works on a single declared element (not on a collection). Therefore, this does not work:

```
const noLinks  = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass');
for (let noLink of noLinks) {
  const matches = noLinks.getElementsByTagName('a');
  matches.setAttribute('role', 'link');
  matches.setAttribute('aria-disabled', 'true');
  matches.removeAttribute('href');
  matches.removeAttribute('rel');
};
```

How can I iterate through the returned elements and get the tags inside of them?

Comment: Don't use `getElementsBy*` methods, `document.querySelectorAll('.myClass a')` does the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `getElementsByTagName` which returns a live HTMLCollection of elements, Your `matches` variable contains an array whereas must be an element to apply to him some properties `href, rel...`, So he needs to be an element not elment**s**, To solve the problem just access to the first element not all of them, or use `querySelector` which return the first matched element if exist.

```js
const noLinks  = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass');
for (let noLink of noLinks) {
                     //v-- access to noLink not noLinks
  const matches = noLink.getElementsByTagName('a')[0]; //<-- or noLinks.querySelector('a')
  matches.setAttribute('role', 'link');
  matches.setAttribute('aria-disabled', 'true');
  matches.removeAttribute('href');
  matches.removeAttribute('rel');
};
```

Comment: I tested both versions of this code. They return the error `Uncaught TypeError: noLinks.querySelector is not a function`, probably because `getElementsByClassName` also returns a collection. This is similar to the errors I was already encountering.

Comment: I copied the code snippet And didn't notice about that your accessing noLinks which needs to be noLink  without (s)!

Comment: The corrected code works. You still have typo in your second comment.

Answer (score 1):

The OP's code could be switched to something more expressive (based on e.g. [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)) like ...

```
document
  .querySelectorAll('.myclass a')
  .forEach(elmNode => {
    elmNode.setAttribute('role', 'link');
    elmNode.setAttribute('aria-disabled', 'true');
    elmNode.removeAttribute('href');
    elmNode.removeAttribute('rel');
  });
```

Comment: This solution works (as does my own posted solution).

Comment: ... and the uncommented -1 vote ("This answer is not useful") was earned due to which specific technical reason/flaw?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking? I don't see any -1 vote.

Comment: @ChrisJ.Zähller ... the comment wasn't for you but for the person who voted yesterday -1. One can see the voting history by clicking on the post's history icon.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works. I'll probably test the other 2 offered solutions & upvote them if they work, but I'm posting this answer so others can see different ways of solving this.

```
// Modify the attributes on the <a> inside the <li> with class "nolink".
const noLinks  = document.getElementsByClassName('nolink');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(noLinks, function(noLink) {
  const matches = noLink.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
  matches.setAttribute('role', 'link');
  matches.setAttribute('aria-disabled', 'true');
  matches.removeAttribute('href');
  matches.removeAttribute('rel');
});
```

Comment: As I answered You correct the script by accessing the first Element `[0]`!

Comment: [Good to know about iterating live collections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66480319/1169519).