# How do I make this better and cleaner?

Tags: javascript

I have this code that remove Items in class btn-danger. I just want to know what can I use instead of for loop to make the code cleaner:

```
var removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger');
for (var i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
 var button = removeCartItemButtons[i];
 button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  var buttonClicked = e.target;
  buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
 });
}
```

Comment: Take advantage of event bubbling and instead of adding a separate even listener on each `btn-danger` element, add a single click listener on the common parent element of all `btn-danger` elements.

Comment: In general, use [`Array` methods](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods). However, in the case of events, as the previous comment says, use [event delegation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) instead of assigning multiple event listeners — it’s more maintainable, and applies to dynamically added elements. Use an [event argument](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback)’s [`target`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Event/target).

Comment: See [the tag info](/tags/event-delegation/info), [What is DOM Event delegation?](/q/1687296/4642212), and [Want to add "addEventListener" on multiple elements with same class](/q/51573435/4642212).

Comment: `Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')).forEach((button) => button.addEventListener('click', (e) => e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove()));`

Comment: What I'm most worried about is the `.parentElement.parentElement` part. this is incredibly prone to errors. as soon as you put as little as a `<span>` inside one of the buttons, or have to add a `<div>` for layout purposes this will break. check out [Element#closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

Answer (score 1):

**General Improvement**

- Use `let` instead of `var`. [See This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var#:%7E:text=let%20allows%20you%20to%20declare,function%20regardless%20of%20block%20scope.)
- If you're just accessing a variable and not changing it, use `const` instead of `let`.
- `document.querySelectorAll()` or `document.querySelector()` are in some cases (like in your case) better than `getElementsByClassName` or `getElementById` or `getElementsByTagName`.
- When iterating over arrays or static node lists, `forEach` is generally a better (more readable) option than a `for` loop. (`querySelectorAll` returns a static node list. You don't need `Array.from`, but if you want to use other Array specific methods use `Array.from` as @Yousaf pointed out)
- Use `function`in the global scope and for `Object.prototype` properties. Use `class` for object constructors. Use `=>` everywhere else. [See This.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6)

Here is how I would have written it

```
document.querySelectorAll('.btn-danger').forEach(btn=>btn.addEventListener('click',e=>e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be shortened to:

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')).forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
    });
});
```

---

This uses:

- `Array.from().forEach()`:

  - [How to correctly iterate through getElementsByClassName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843581/how-to-correctly-iterate-through-getelementsbyclassname)>
- Arrow functions

  - [What's the meaning of "=>" (an arrow formed from equals & greater than) in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas)

---

Since the array functions can be [re-written without the `{}`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-a-return-statement-in-es6-arrow-functions), an one-liner would look like:

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')).forEach((button) => button.addEventListener('click', (e) => e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove()));
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity; is there any particular reason/advantage for preferring `Array.from(...).forEach(...)` over `document.querySelectorAll('.btn-danger').forEach(...)`, please? Thanks

Comment: Yes @secan, that won't work since nodelists don't have a foreach. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39146365/5625547).

Comment: [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll#accessing_the_matches) returns a static node list that can be iterated with `forEach()`, as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/ujkwvath/

Comment: Ow sorry thought you were using getElementsByClassName. Not sure if queryAll is better than array.from.