# select all items with class name using document.querySelector

Tags: javascript

I have 4 images using the class .light-image

I am trying to change them all using js. The code below only grabs the first item, how can I make it grab all 4?

```
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)").matches) {
  document.querySelector('.light-image').src="/app/themes/piranha/assets/public/images/light-open.svg";
}
```

Comment: You want `for( const el of document.querySelectorAll('.light-image') ) { el.src = "etc"; }`

Comment: Thank you for responding, I tried that and it didnt work, it didnt grab any

Comment: Have you used your debugger? If not, why not?

Comment: @JustinBlayney If you tried just changing to `document.querySelectorAll('.light-image').src="/app/themes/piranha/assets/public/images/light-open.svg";` then it won't work. `querySelectorAll` returns a node list which you need to iterate over and set each elements src property. [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: querySelector**All** should work. Be wary of the camel-cased method name.

Comment: @Ryan Wilson

 could you show me how that would look please?

Comment: @JustinBlayney If you scroll down the link I provided for `querySelectorAll` it shows how to iterate the node list.

Comment: Also: @Dai _showed_ you how you might iterate over the node list in the very first comment.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `querySelector` use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) that returns a node list of all elements matching the selector (not just the first one).

Then you need to iterate it over the node list.

```
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)").matches) {
  let itemList = [...document.querySelectorAll('.light-image')]
  itemList.forEach(el => el.src="/app/themes/piranha/assets/public/images/light-open.svg";)
}
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71999920/18762628) for more information

Comment: I think you mean [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Comment: Thanks @Andy. Didn't notice that

Comment: Thank you all, Dai I cant mark yours as answer

Comment: @JustinBlayney you can upvote his comment

Comment: I don't think we should be encouraging people to use `.forEach`. We should direct people to use `for(of)` instead.

Comment: @Dai I wouldn't really say one or the other is better in this context, it's simply a matter of whether you prefer a functional or an imperative approach.

Comment: @Etheryte `.forEach` is demonstrasbly not "functional" because it creates a closure and invariably causes side-effects. `for(of)` is superior in every way, honestly. Anyway, the other reason to avoid `.forEach` is because it isn't defined on `NodeList` (browsers do implement it for compatibility, [but it isn't in the spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#nodelist)).

Comment: @Dai For all practical intents and purposes, none of those nuances really matter. This is similar to a-la worrying about the performance difference between `for` and `forEach`. For nearly every use case it's completely unimportant and trumped by whatever the convention is in the codebase you're in and what's readable.

Comment: @Etheryte If readability matters then `for(of)` is definitely the winner :)

Comment: @JustinBlayney please mark as answer if it helped.

Comment: @Dai  I wasn't aware of the difference,. I preferred forEach as it is oneLiner. I would love to read more if you have a link

Comment: @liorbakalo You can use `for(of)` as a "one-liner" too y'know. As for links and resources, I'm unsure what you're looking for, really.

Answer (score 0):

### `querySelector` vs `querySelectorAll`

Your current code works on the assumption that `document.querySelector` always returns a single (and non-`null`, non-`undefined`) `HTMLImageElement` object, whereupon your code immediately sets the `.src` property.

However, the `querySelectorAll` function [returns a `NodeList<TElement>` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), which is an iterable collection of HTML elements instead of a singular nullable object reference.

If you're coming from a jQuery background you might be used to how jQuery's `$('selector')` function *always* returns a (wrapped) collection of elements, but it has an API design that allows you to set properties and call member functions on all elements in the collection as though the returned object represented a single element.

...unfortunately that style of API design (does it have a name?) doesn't apply anymore (<sub>good riddance...</sub>), so you need be familiar with how singular (scalar) object references compare to iterables.

In modern JavaScript, when you have an iterable collection you need to use `for(of)` to access, edit, and work with each object in the collection, like so:

(I changed your selector to `img.light-image` to prevent any non-`<img/>` elements from being inadvertently returned).

```js
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)").matches) {
  const images = document.querySelectorAll('img.light-image'); // <-- `images: NodeList<HTMLImageElement>`
  for( const img of images ) { // <-- `img: HTMLImageElement`
    img.src = "/app/themes/piranha/assets/public/images/light-open.svg";
  }
}
```

In old and obsolete (and especially *non-portable*) JavaScript, like from the days when we had to use jQuery, it was common to use the `.forEach` member function to succinctly iterate through a collection - however this is unwise, unsafe, and just passé now; namely because `.forEach` is not well-defined: for example, `NodeList<T>.forEach` is not standardized or in any formal specifications, according to the MDN.

### A better idea:

Fun-fact: **you don't need any JavaScript!**

What you're trying to accomplish can be achieved using *only* CSS:

Remove your script and open your `.css` file (or inline `<style>` element) and put this instead:

See here: [Is it possible to set the equivalent of a src attribute of an img tag in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182716/is-it-possible-to-set-the-equivalent-of-a-src-attribute-of-an-img-tag-in-css)

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

    img.light-image {
        content: url("/app/themes/piranha/assets/public/images/light-open.svg")
    }

}
```