# Javascript-function only changing 2 of 3 Elements

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

So i wrote a fairly simple function to remove the "hidden" class from 3 items, when another element is clicked. Onclick it gets the 3 items right but it only changes item1+3 and item2 needs another click. I have absolutly no clue why this is happening.

https://codepen.io/zafire/pen/ExexWre

```js
function lmao() {
  const collection = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");
  console.log(collection.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    collection[i].classList.remove("hidden");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 27px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.nothidden {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span onclick="lmao()">arrow</span>
  <br><br><br>
  <span class="hidden">item1</span>
  <br>
  <span class="hidden">item2</span>
  <br>
  <span class="hidden">item3</span>
  <br>
</div>
```

Also i would like to notice solved this now differently but im still curious why this particular code does not work.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66480319/16688813).

Comment: Also instead of classes showing and hiding give them `class="menuItem" hidden` and use `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {  const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll(".menuItem");  const toggle = show => menuItems.forEach(item => item.hidden = !show);   toggle(1);  }) ; `
`

Answer (score 3):

If you read the MDN docs of [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

> **Warning**: This is a **live** HTMLCollection. Changes in the DOM will reflect in the array as the changes occur. If an element selected by this array no longer qualifies for the selector, it will automatically be removed. Be aware of this for iteration purposes.

So when you remove the class from an element the list is affected.

You can create an array from the initial selection

```
const collection = [...document.getElementsByClassName("hidden")];
```

of you can use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```
const collection = document.querySelectorAll(".hidden");
```

which states

> The Document method `querySelectorAll()` returns a **static (not live)** NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.

and now you can iterate over it with no worries.

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense. I would probably have never thought of that possiblity. Thanks alot man!